# Getting and Setting SPUser / SPUserCollection field in Visual Studio Workflow 2013

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, user, visual-studio-2013

Can anyone please guide me to Get and Set SPUser / SPUserCollection field using Visual Studio Workflow? When I read the field using REST API, it is only giving the User IDs (integers). Now, I have no idea, how to use these to set the users in a SPMultiUser field. If at all, I have to use these IDs to query the User Info list, it would involve multiple calls, since there are multiple IDs returned. I believe, this won't be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard Lookup action to read a user value, please see picture 2.
To setup a user value you can just write UserID, if you have several users you need to split it via ";#;#", as example "1;#;#10;#;#" (sets users with ID 1 and 10)

[image]
[image]
[image]